# Optimizing MySQL query to get the right template for a page

Tags: php, mysql, inheritance, optimization, query-optimization

The MySQL-query below is working like this:
In a treeview-like structure, it's searching for a template to use.

For example:

- Home (tpl: home) - (lvl: pagId)

  - Carrousel (tpl: carrousel) - (lvl: subId)
  - Carrousel item 1 (tpl: {inherit from parent}) - (lvl: sub2Id)
- Contact (tpl: contact) - (lvl: pagId)

  - Address (tpl: {inherit from parent}) - (lvl: subId)
- Forum (tpl: forum) - (lvl: pagId)

  - Topic (tpl: forum) - (lvl: subId)
  - Message (tpl: forum) - (lvl: subId)
- FAQ (tpl: faq) - (lvl: pagId)

  - Question 1 (tpl: question) - (lvl: subId)
  - Question 2 (tpl: question) - (lvl: subId)
  - Subquestion 1 (tpl: {inherit from parent}) - (lvl: sub2Id)
  - Subquestion 2 (tpl: subquestion) - (lvl: sub2Id)

When a child has no templateId, it's inheriting the template of his parent.
But when a child has a templateId, it's keeping his own template.

Problem is that the query below has a duration of approximately 1 second and it's a query which is frequently used in an API. How to optimize the query below without losing its working? Or will it be better to split the query?

```
SELECT 
                        `c`.*, 
                        `c`.`pagId` AS `parentPagId`,
                        `c`.`subId` AS `parentSubId`,
                        `c`.`sub2Id` AS `parentSub2Id`,
                        `c`.`sub3Id` AS `parentSub3Id`,
                        IF( 
                            `template`.`templateName` IS NOT NULL,
                            `template`.`templateName`,
                            (
                                SELECT 
                                    IF(
                                        `template`.`templateName` IS NOT NULL,
                                        `template`.`templateName`,
                                        'default'
                                    )
                                FROM
                                    `content`
                                LEFT JOIN
                                    `template`
                                ON
                                    `content`.`templateId` = `template`.`id`
                                WHERE
                                    CASE WHEN 
                                        ( `content`.`sub3Id` = '' AND `content`.`sub2Id` != '' AND `content`.`templateId` != 0 AND `content`.`templateId` IS NOT NULL )
                                    THEN 
                                         `content`.`sub2Id` = `c`.`sub2Id`
                                    WHEN 
                                        ( `content`.`sub2Id` = '' AND `content`.`subId` != '' AND `content`.`templateId` != 0 AND `content`.`templateId` IS NOT NULL )
                                    THEN 
                                        `content`.`subId` = `c`.`subId`
                                    WHEN 
                                        ( `content`.`subId` = '' AND `content`.`pagId` != '' AND `content`.`templateId` != 0 AND `content`.`templateId` IS NOT NULL)
                                    THEN 
                                        `content`.`pagId` = `c`.`pagId`
                                    ELSE
                                        ''
                                    END
                                AND
                                    `content`.`siteId` = '1' 
                                AND
                                    `content`.`langId` = '1'
                                AND
                                    `content`.`active` = 1
                                LIMIT 1
                            )
                        ) AS `template`
                    FROM 
                        `content` `c`
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        `template` 
                        ON `c`.`templateId` = `template`.`id`
                    WHERE 
                        `c`.`siteId` = '1' 
                    AND 
                        `c`.`langId` = '1'
                    AND
                        `c`.`active` = 1
                    ORDER BY 
                        `c`.`order`, 
                        `c`.`pagId`, 
                        `c`.`subId`, 
                        `c`.`sub2Id`, 
                        `c`.`sub3Id`
```

**UPDATE**
I'm having 2 tables:

Table 1 ("content") fields:

- pagId
- subId
- sub2Id
- sub3Id
- content
- templateId

Table 2 ("template") fields:

- id
- templateName

What I want to do (and what's working, but is taking too much time in this query):

1. Getting all pages from database
2. If content.templateId > 0: get templateName from row with template.id = content.templateId
3. If content.templateId = 0 or NULL: get parent template -> this is what the subquery does...
4. If template not results in a valid templateName: template = "default"

Answer (score 0):

You've create a very complex SQL command here. This doesn't make much sense. It doesn't help, of course, that the table definitions are missing from your question. We should guess them?

I'm confused, you have `template.templateName` and `template.id`, sometime you use one, then the other? Always use the `id` when you have it. It should be a unique indexed number, whereas the name can be anything and might not even be unique or indexed.

It is clear to me you try to do too much in one query. Take a step back and write down, in simple steps, what it is you want to do.

1. You seem to have a 'content' table for the content of each page. If it refers to a template, you're done, get it.
2. If it doesn't refer to a template, ask the parent for it's template.

It should be as easy as that. You should probably do this in PHP, and only ask the database for information when it is needed. You would be left with one simple query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM content 
WHERE siteId = 1 AND langId = 1 AND active = 1 AND pagId = ?
```

Note that I only ask for the page I am interested in. I might be mistaken but it seems you request all the pages in the database. You probably only need one.